# Return CGValues Resulting in Xcode Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cgfloat

So I have a function that when called, needs to return a `CGFloat` value. However, Xcode responds with an error saying: "CGFloat is not convertible to ()". I have looked around the web, but none of the conversions seem to be working for me.

Here is my function

```
func update() {
    point2.y += 1.39
    return point2.y //<<<LINE OF ERROR<<<//
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not specify a return type.

In Swift, you denote this with arrow (`->`) notation.

Try

```swift
func update() -> CGFloat {
    point2.y += 1.39
    return point2.y
}
```

"CGFloat is not convertible to ()" means that your method returns something of type CGFloat, when a return type of Void (or `()`) is expected.

Comment: @24GHz I'm glad I could help. If this provided an answer to your question, consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that we both gain [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Oh sure, yes. I have already accepted an answer recently, so I cant for another 4 minutes. But once that timer runs out I will most definitely accept it :)